# How to pass arguments to subprocess python instance

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I'm opening multiple python instances using multiprocessing package and subprocess object. So basicly 10 different python instances that have two sockets in them that serve as client socket and server socket.

Here is example how I launch two python instances with two different files:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess


def task1():
    print('This is task1')
    subprocess.Popen(['python','server_client_pair1.py'])
    sleep(1)
def task2():
    # block for a moment
    sleep(1)
    # display a message
    print('This is task2')
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','server_client_pair2.py'])
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a process
    process1 = Process(target=task1)
    sleep(.5)
    process2 = Process(target=task2)
    sleep(.5)
    # run the process
    process1.start()
    sleep(.5)
    process2.start()
    sleep(.5)
    # wait for the process to finish
    print('Waiting for the process...')
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

I need to pass argument which changes variable PORT which is port number and I'd like to change it with PORT+1 every loop in the file ('server_client_pair.py')

Right now I have working code that uses 10 different server_client_pair.py files (server_client_pair1.py, server_client_pair2.py, server_client_pair3.py, etc)

I'm wondering how to do this with just one file. Any help would be welcome.

*edited the post for more info

Comment: Thanks for posting. Can you please provide a MWE. What do you mean by HOST? Where is this defined? Where does it go? You're a little light on the details.

Comment: You can always just define `HOST = some_int`, and then in your for loop pass `HOST+i`. It's hard to offer advice without more detail.

Comment: You know how to pass command line parameters, right?  `sys.argv`?

Comment: No I have never passed (used) command line parameters. Sounds like this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add arguments to your

> server_client_pair.py

file then
it will work for you as well :

```
def task1():  
for i in range(10):
    subprocess.Popen(['python','server_client_pair.py',str(i)])
    sleep(1)
```

check here to learn how to pass arguments to your python files:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thank you.

Comment: your welcome, i made an edit to the answer check the link @ozunm